# How do you log soap XML requests and responses to and from Sharepoint within sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, soap

I'm using sharepoint soap web services

I would like to turn on some logging **on the sharepoint side** that logs the incoming and outgoing soap xml messages.

can it be done??

Comment: Which Sharepoint Version ?

Comment: 2010 or 2013 either
(Sorry i didn't get back to you sooner i didn't get the notification pop up for some reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Sharepoint,both 2010 and 2013 there is [Diagnostic Logging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748619(v=office.14).aspx) but I think it does not write anything on SOAP messages, for this reason I would look for a solution inside IIS.

Sharepoint 2013 using WCF, you can use [Configure Message Loggin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx), very simple to use by editing the web.config.

Sharepoint 2010 use old-style asmx, in this case is slightly harder, you can write a `SoapExtension` at this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7w06t139(v=vs.100).aspx) you can see a simple implementation and this [Stackoverflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563267/how-to-create-a-web-config-file-to-get-soapextension-loading) explain how-to register.

Also you can try the [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) program.